# Nested datatable in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to fetch the questions and the associated answers. I am able to get the questions fine but the nested datatable does not even recognize the properties each answer has, and this is also pointed out by the IDE as well. Maybe this is not the right way to go about this. How do I iterate over the answers associated with each question ?

```
 <h:dataTable value="#{questionBacking.recentlyAskedQuestions}" var="questions"
                 rendered="#{questionBacking.recentlyAskedQuestions.size() > 0}"
                 border="1">

                <h:column>

                   <h:outputText  value="#{questions.questionTitle}" />

                   <br/>
                   <h:outputText  value="#{questions.questionBody}" />

               </h:column>

              <h:dataTable value="#{questions.answers}" var="answers">
              <tr>
                  <h:outputText  value="#{answers.answer}" />
              </tr>


              </h:dataTable>

  </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to put columns inside a `<h:column>`.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{questionBacking.recentlyAskedQuestions}" var="question" rendered="#{not empty questionBacking.recentlyAskedQuestions}">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText  value="#{question.questionTitle}" />
        <br/>
        <h:outputText  value="#{question.questionBody}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:dataTable value="#{question.answers}" var="answer">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText  value="#{answer.answer}" />
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

*(note that I changed the `rendered` and the `var` attributes to be a bit more self-documenting, you might want to rename `questionTitle`, `questionBody` and `answer` to `title`, `body` and `body` respectively as well so that you don't keep duplicating the meaning)*

Comment: answers.answer is supposed to make a call to getAnswer(), but editor still does not even actually list "answer" as a property. Despite IDE's suggestion I put it in there and it still does not get the answer - it shows an empty column.

Comment: Then the problem is caused by something else. Perhaps there are just no answers? If the property name was wrong, you'd have gotten a `PropertyNotFoundException` anyway.

Comment: Even if I replace it with <h:outputText  value="#{answer.answerz}" /> it still does not give me any errors. It is very strange indeed because getAnswer is defined in the Answer entity class.

Comment: That still won't be displayed when there are no answers. You need to debug `#{question.answers}`.

Comment: This is what blows my mind. I doubled checked everything. http://imageshack.us/f/217/jsfh.jpg/

Comment: Ignore the EL autocompletion of the IDE. You shouldn't expect that an IDE is smart enough to figure that (this appies not only to Netbeans, but also to Eclipse). What does `<h:outputText  value="#{question.answers}" />` say? Put a breakpoint on `getAnswers()` method of the `Question` class. As far now, I don't see any other cause than that the `List<Answer>` of the `Question` is simply empty.

Comment: I debugged it like this:  <h:outputText  value="#{question.answers.size()}" />  and it prints the number of answers per question correctly, but I am not able to get the answers under this line still.

Comment: question have other attributes such as "user" besides "answers". It does not print any of its attributes inside the embedded datatable whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing mentioned in BalusC's answer using PrimeFaces as well. Just replace `<h:dataTable>` with `<p:dataTable>` and the same goes for column tags as well. You can create nested datatable with PrimeFaces. I recommend people to use PrimeFaces as it reduces the amount of time people spend on writing/modifying css definitions.